# C# Pass ListView Items from a Function to a ListView on a form?

Tags: c#, .net, listview, listviewitem

i am trying to do the following:

I have a function.. which Queries SQL and gets some data from a database.. now i want to display those values in a listview which is on a form. The function is in a SQL Class.

It works for one item only, but if i want for example 5 items to be passed it wont work since it only passes the last time, which is logical when you see the code.

I cant seem to figure out, how to "referance" a listvie object from a form to the function and pass the items to it.

Here is the code: (i know it returns only one item now, i tried different things.. none worked):

```
    public ListViewItem SQL_GetLogsHistory(string WKS)
    {
        SqlCommand mySQLCommand = new SqlCommand(Properties.Settings.Default.SQL_GetLogsHistroy, SQLconn);
        mySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WKS", WKS);
        SqlDataReader reader = mySQLCommand.ExecuteReader();
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();


        while (reader.Read())
        {
            item = new ListViewItem(new[] { 

                reader.GetValue(4).ToString(), // Timestamp
                reader.GetValue(2).ToString() // Log

            });

        }

        reader.Close();
        return item;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use yield return:

```
   public IEnumerable<ListViewItem> SQL_GetLogsHistory(string WKS)
    {
        SqlCommand mySQLCommand = new SqlCommand(Properties.Settings.Default.SQL_GetLogsHistroy, SQLconn);
        mySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WKS", WKS);
        SqlDataReader reader = mySQLCommand.ExecuteReader();
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();


        while (reader.Read())
        {
            yield return new ListViewItem(new[] { 

                reader.GetValue(4).ToString(), // Timestamp
                reader.GetValue(2).ToString() // Log

            });

        }

        reader.Close();
        return item;
    }
```

This will reduce multiple enumeration of your data.  You can then use this method to create a `List<ListViewItem>` if required:

```
var list = SQL_GetLogsHistory(WKS).ToList();
```

Or you could directly use this as your list view data source:

```
listView.DataSource = SQL_GetLogsHistory(WKS);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can have list of items

```
List<ListViewItem> items = new List<ListViewItem>();
```

inside your loop create new `ListViewItem` and set the properties and add it to list

```
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        item = new ListViewItem(new[] { 

            reader.GetValue(4).ToString(), // Timestamp
            reader.GetValue(2).ToString() // Log

        });
      items.Add(item);

    }
```

finally return `items` from the method and change the signature of the method as below

```
public List<ListViewItem> SQL_GetLogsHistory(string WKS)
```

**Side Note: better to use `using` statements for `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader`**

```
public List<ListViewItem> SQL_GetLogsHistory(string WKS)
{
    List<ListViewItem> items = new List<ListViewItem>();
    using (SqlCommand mySQLCommand = new SqlCommand(Properties.Settings.Default.SQL_GetLogsHistroy, SQLconn))
    {
        mySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WKS", WKS);
        using (SqlDataReader reader = mySQLCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ListViewItem item =  new ListViewItem(new[] { 
                            reader.GetValue(4).ToString(), // Timestamp
                            reader.GetValue(2).ToString() // Log
                        });
                items.Add(item);
            }
        }

    }
    return items;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you just need to return a `List<ListViewItem>` like this?

```
public List<ListViewItem> SQL_GetLogsHistory(string WKS)
{
    SqlCommand mySQLCommand = new SqlCommand(Properties.Settings.Default.SQL_GetLogsHistroy, SQLconn);
    mySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WKS", WKS);
    SqlDataReader reader = mySQLCommand.ExecuteReader();
    List<ListViewItem> items = new List<ListViewItem>();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var item = new ListViewItem(new[] { 

            reader.GetValue(4).ToString(), // Timestamp
            reader.GetValue(2).ToString() // Log

        });

        items.Add(item);
    }

    reader.Close();
    return items;
}
```